# NGINX method not working when connecting IP to Domain

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fastapi, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I an using docker and fast api to host my web app. My docker port is runing on 5000 port. I am using nginx for forwarding all my post request on "IP":5000/face_ai to "domain"/face_ai. I am able to see my root of fast api through domain but cannot able to access /home or /face_ai methods of it.

fast api code:

```
@buyume_app.post("/face_ai",status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK)
async def face_image(response: Response, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()
    nparr = np.fromstring(contents, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    face= face_extractor(img)

    if file.content_type != "image/jpeg" or face is False:
        raise HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
        detail=f'Face not found in {file.filename}. Please provide a valid input',)
    result= calculation(img)
    return result
```

docker-compose :

```
GNU nano 4.8                                                                                           docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  fastapi:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.cpu
    environment:
      #- NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all
      #- LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64
      - LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1
    ports:
      - "5000:8888"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code/app
    runtime: nvidia
```

Dockerfile:

```
#FROM python:3.10.3-slim-bullseye

FROM nvidia/cuda:11.4.2-runtime-ubuntu20.04
#FROM tensorflow/serving:latest-devel-gpu
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu



COPY . .

ENV TZ=Asia/Dubai
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt install -y tzdata

ENV LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG
ENV CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1

RUN apt-get -y update

#RUN apt-get update && \
    #apt-get install -y curl gnupg && \
   # distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) && \
  #  curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add - && \
 #   curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list && \
#    apt-get update

#RUN apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2

RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip libffi-dev libssl-dev libcairo2 libcairo2-dev libgirepository1.0-dev pkg-config


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir  -r ./requirements.txt
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 tree  -y

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
#ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH


# CMD sh
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:buyume_app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8888"]
```

nginx config:

```
server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #



        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name ai.buyume.io; # managed by Certbot


        location /face_ai {
                proxy_pass http://ip:5000/face_ai;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

I want to access all my fast api methods like /home and /face_ai through my domain